# Different title on post page than front page, wordpress

Tags: wordpress, title

is it possible for each post to have two titles with Wordpress. One that is used on the specific post page, and one that is shown on the front page,category page, search page etc.

How can this be done?

Comment: Yes, what kind of title do you want and did you try anything ?

Comment: I own a newspaper and I want each article/post to have two different titles. One that is shown on the front page, a kind of "Click here it 'cause its cool" that is shown on the front page to be more appealing to the reader. And one title that is shown instead of the first on on the actual post page. There the title would be more informative.

I think the best solution would be to have a custom field like the "Excerpt" field, for the custom title. Such that if the author wants to have another title on the spesific post page it is possible.

I hope thats a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may try something like this

```
<title>
    <?php
        if (is_single()) { wp_title('',true); }
        else { bloginfo('name') ?> &#8212; <?php bloginfo('description'); }
    ?>
</title>
```

Also, check [this article](http://wplifeguard.com/seo-friendly-dynamic-title-for-wordpress/).

Comment: I want a more flexible solution. See my comment to your comment. :)